# Target iPhone Simulator Macro Not Working

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Using the `TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR` macro results in the same constant values being defined in am application. For example:

```
#ifdef TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
NSString * const Mode = @"Simulator";
#else
NSString * const Mode = @"Device";
#endif

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
   ...
   NSLog(@"Mode: %@", Mode);
   ...
}
```

Always results in "Mode: Simulator" being logged. I'm currently running XCode 3.2.4 if that helps. Thanks.

Comment: TARGET_IPHONE_SIMUATOR has a typo (missing 'L'), and it shows up in the google search preview as such.

Comment: @wilsonmichaelpatrick fixed

Answer (score 109, accepted):

`TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR` is defined on the device (but defined to false). The fix is:

```
#include <TargetConditionals.h> // required in Xcode 8+

#if TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
NSString * const Mode = @"Simulator";
#else
NSString * const Mode = @"Device";
#endif
```

Not sure when this was changed. I'm fairly sure it was possible to use 'ifdef' in the past.

Comment: This is a common mistake in many libs, e.h. here: https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCIntrospect/issues/24. Thanks for sharing your solution!

Comment: Thanks for the topic; I thought I was going mad, or worse (forgetting my many years a C development).

Comment: TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR is deprecated in iOS 9. Use TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR in XCode 7

Answer (score 13):

For me explicitly including `TargetConditionals.h` helped

```
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
```

Comment: Seems to me that from some specific Xcode version on (I am currently using 7.3.1) this is necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Try TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR, as TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

I would try implement macro if its going to be used on different classes through out the app.

in pch file ,

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#define isSimulator() YES
#else
#define isSimulator() NO
#endif
```

and in any class I can check by calling isSimulator().

Answer (score 1):

For some reason TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR doesn't work for me in xcode v6.4 . The snippet below works perfectly :

```
#if (!arch(i386) && !arch(x86_64))
  camera           = Camera()
#else
  camera           = MockCamera()
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift:

```swift
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
    showSimulatorOnlyError()
#endif
```