# Programmatically detect if app is being run on device or simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, simulator, detect

I'd like to know whether my app is being run on device or simulator at run time.  Is there a way to detect this?

Reason being to test bluetooth api with simulator:
http://volcore.limbicsoft.com/2009/09/iphone-os-31-gamekit-pt-1-woooohooo.html

Comment: No need for checking for that at runtime, just use the TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR definition to distinguish that case from the running on device case.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

```
#if TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR

//Simulator

#else

// Device

#endif
```

Pls refer this previous SO question also [What #defines are set up by Xcode when compiling for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146986/what-defines-are-setup-by-xcode-when-compiling-for-iphone)

Comment: Note that these are compile time macros and not available at runtime.

Comment: #include "TargetConditionals.h"   // if your source is in c

Comment: Does the StackOverflow crowd have a reading comprehension problem? The question was to ask about distinguishing at *runtime* not at compile time! The right answer is the SIM macro by Fernando Cervantes, and not this one. Yet as of this comment writing, this wrong answer has 32 points and the right one has but 3.

Comment: @StCredZero Perhaps that is because code compiled to run on the simulator can't run on a device and vice versa, so in the end it doesn't matter wether you do the check at compile time or at run time.

Comment: @JohanKool It does matter in some cases, such as if you're writing a static library that's used in other people's apps. You don't have the luxury of compile-time checking, because your code has already been compiled. So your check needs to be at run-time. Case in point: Including a warning msg for the developer for this Xcode 8 simulator bug: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/179846

Comment: @RizwanSattar That doesn't make any sense. You need to compile two versions of the library anyways. One is for the simulator, which uses a different architecture than the physical devices. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 18):

I created a macro in which you can specify which actions you want to perform inside parentheses and these actions will only be performed if the device is being simulated.

```
#define SIM(x) if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice].model lowercaseString] rangeOfString:@"simulator"].location != NSNotFound){x;}
```

This is used like this:

```
SIM(NSLog(@"This will only be logged if the device is simulated"));
```

Comment: UIDevice's `model` property doesn't contain `simulator` word from iOS 9

Answer (score 5):

**TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR** is defined on the device (but defined to false). and defined as below

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
NSString * const DeviceMode = @"Simulator";
#else
NSString * const DeviceMode = @"Device";
#endif
```

Just use `DeviceMode` to know between device and simulator

Answer (score 5):

Check if **simulator**

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
// Simulator
#endif
```

Check if **device**

```
#if !(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)
// Device
#endif
```

Check for **both**

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
// Simulator
#else
// Device
#endif
```

Please note that you should not `ifdef` on 
`TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR` because it will always be defined to either `1` or `0`.

Comment: Thank you a lot! ifdef is an evil)

Answer (score 4):

## From XCode 9.3+ , Swift

```
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
//Simulator
#else
//Real device
#endif
```

Helps you to code against device type specific.

Comment: That new macro is for swift only: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-DontLinkElementID_68

Comment: Yeah, i forgot to mention it. Post edited. tnx @stonedauwg

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427888/target-iphone-simulator-macro-not-working) preprocessor macro to distinguish between device and simulator targets.

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code:

```
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
   // iOS Simulator
#else
   // Device
#endif
```

Works for `Swift 4` and `Xcode 9.4.1`

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is looking for `Unity` solution i did this, the only way i found how.

```
using System.Globalization;

public static bool IsArm() {
        return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(SystemInfo.processorType, "ARM", CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) >= 0;
    }
```