# Knowing if the app is running in a testing environment

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is there a way to know if the program is running in the development environment? I'm using Flurry Analytics and want to pass it a different app id, so the data doesn't get dirty with my tests during development.

What I'd like is something like this:

```
Boolean isDevEnv = .... (is this a test in the simulator or device,
                         OR is it a real user that downloaded the 
                         app through the app store?)
if (isDevEnv)
  [FlurryAnalytics startSession:@"firstAppId"];
else
  [FlurryAnalytics startSession:@"secondAppId"];
```

To be clear, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775420/programmatically-detect-if-app-is-being-run-on-device-or-simulator) is not what I'm after, because I test using a real device as well as the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems this is done by default by Xode, in the Project's Build Settings, under `Apple LLVM compiler 3.1 - Preprocessing` (this is in Xcode 4.3.2, for future reference), a setting called `DEBUG` is populated with the value `1`.

So, I didn't really have to do anything, just this in the code (in my case in the AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method):

```
[FlurryAnalytics startSession:DEBUG ? @"firstAppId" : @"secondAppId"];
```

Answer (score 2):

In the build settings you'll have to set flags, depending on the building env.

Then, use #ifdef and #define to set the appid.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#    define APPID ...    
#else
#    define APPID ...
#endif
```

Comment: I'm probably doing something stupid wrong: in Targets, I select the only one, then go to the Build Settings tab, then Add Build Setting, which adds a row in the User-Defined group (I named it "TESTING"), then for each one (Debug and Release) I click on the plus sign, what values do I put there?

Answer (score 0):

In your build settings, define a new flag for the App Store release version. Then use `#ifdef` to determine at compile time which appid to use.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use `DEBUG` flag and `DEBUG` environment, create a new build configuration (duplicate Release configuration) and in the build settings Preprocessor Macros add a FlurryAnalytics flag. In your code check `if(FlurryAnalytics)`. Create a new scheme in XCode that creates ipa using this new release build configuration.