# How do I know if objective C code is running in iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator

I've tried

```
#ifdef TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
  static BOOL isSimulator = YES;
#endif
```

But for both device and simulator, the isSimulator variable always comes out to 1.

I need a way to figure out if the code running is on iOS simulator or on a device.

Comment: As you can see on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775420/programmatically-detect-if-app-is-being-run-on-device-or-simulator you can check where is running your app at runtime (not at compile time as you provided) like this way: #define SIM(x) if ... (by Fernando Cervantes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code snippet only checks if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR is defined (even if it's defined as 0)

Try checking like this instead:
(the #error will simply show as a compilation error in Xcode)

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#error Simulator
#else
#error Device
#endif
```