# How to check if app is running from xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using a test library to see me crash report, and I need to know if the app is running from Xcode, I know that exist the DEGUB parameter, but it does not work because if install app from xcode and open it, DEGUB parameter will be in YES.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically detect if app is being run on device or simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775420/programmatically-detect-if-app-is-being-run-on-device-or-simulator)

Comment: That's not his question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not the question, I need to know if the device is running, while is connected to xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want, but you can check if the cable is plugged in, so if it's just for testing the solution should be enough.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryLevel]
```

or

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] UIDeviceBatteryState]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but may be I want to use the app and charger the device. :(